# Are workflow comments customizable?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

Does anyone know of any way to customise the Workflow Comments box that appears in Sitecore if you enable the "comments" option?

[image: sitecore workflow comments]

I'm looking to extend this a little ... but can't see this referenced in any sitecore javascript or shell files - I'm guessing I will need to build a custom dialog in its entirety to implement the functionality I want, but not 100% where to start!

Comment: It's not clear what customization do you need? is it all about the look of the dialog? Or do you want to do something extra with the comment in addition to just saving it to database? Or?

Comment: Pretty much completely replace that dialog - so far I've got a solution working that replaces it with custom actions that push the user off into another "application" within SiteCore. It's dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up putting a solution in place that, broadly, composes of a custom action, containing the relevant form that we need. The information that the user submitted was then parsed, and passed to the workflow as comments (this particular workflow command was hidden from users, so they had to go through our custom one). 
Not ideal, but works!